# The focus of the Akeida

Tags: korban, genesis-bereishith, binding-of-isaac

Why is the ***binding*** of Yitzhak the focus of the narrative more so than the attempted offering itself by Avraham?

Comment: Where do you see that it is?

Comment: Akeida means the binding of Yitzhak, not the offering of Avraham. Seems the importance is in the binding as opposed to the attempted offering that follows.

Comment: Do you mean to ask why is the episode colloquially referred to as the Binding of Isaac / Akeidas Yitzchak, as opposed to something else like Avraham offering his son?

Comment: He binds him to the wood on top of the altar. I.e. the act of binding him *is* the act of offering him, and the climax of the entire episode

Comment: If you want some sources that use the term Akeidas Yitzchak (and thus you'll ask, why is it referred to that way), consider adding to your question [Rosh Hashana 16a](https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_Hashanah.16a.16?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi), [Tamid 31b](https://www.sefaria.org/Tamid.31b.4?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi), [Vayikra Rabbah](https://www.sefaria.org/Vayikra_Rabbah.2.11?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=bi), [Midrash Tanchuma](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Vayera.23.9?vhe=Midrash_Tanchuma_--_Torat_Emet&lang=bi), etc.

Comment: It's also found in [Rosh Hashana](https://www.sefaria.org/Machzor_Rosh_Hashanah_Ashkenaz%2C_Musaf%2C_First_Day_of_Rosh_Hashana%2C_Amidah.49?vhe=The_Metsudah_Machzor._Metsudah_Publications,_New_York_--_he_(paragraph_ed.)&lang=bi) prayers

Comment: @Josh K. Is not the climax of the episode the raising of the knife and the intervention of the angels to prevent the deed? As opposed to the binding alone of which the episode is titled?

Comment: @robev. Yes precisely what I'm wondering.

Comment: Then perhaps you may consider rewording the question to better reflect your intent

Comment: The raising of the knife is of course the true climax of the story from a narrative standpoint, @Ephraim. From a spiritual standpoint, however, binding your son to a pile of wood on top of an altar represents the true 'point of no return' and in a certain sense the true test. Abraham is evasive about just what they're doing on the mountain until that point in time....it's as if G-d stops being just a voice in his head and starts being something he can't deny

Answer (score -1):

'ה never told אברהם to slaughter his son. Rather he was commanded to prepare his son ("bring him up") to be an offering i.e. bind him (see [Rashi's comment on Bereishis 22:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.22.2?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en)).
Therefore it follows to refer to the event as "the binding of יצחק" because that was the actual test, to go up and bind him. Nothing more.

Comment: Were the Jews also only commanded to tie animals up on Har Eval and not slaughter them? אֲבָנִים שְׁלֵמוֹת תִּבְנֶה, אֶת-מִזְבַּח יְהוָה אֱלֹהֶיךָ; וְהַעֲלִיתָ עָלָיו עוֹלֹת, לַיהוָה אֱלֹהֶיךָ.

Comment: Why don't we call it עליית יצחק then? This doesn't explain the choice of the root עקד

Comment: @DoubleAA the question about har eval is very good, but it's a question on Rashi , not a question on me.

Comment: @DoubleAA with regards to your second question,(also a good question) the questioner (Ephraim77) asked about the focus of the narrative not the choice of words. I gave a possible answer to his question.